# Strings and UIImages in the same Dictionary Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, string, swift, uiimage

I am quite new to Swift and Xcode. I have made a UITableView to display specific posts from instagram. Due to other changes I have made recently (to get other things to work) I need to add both UIImages and Strings to a Dictionary (which the data is then put into the table) so everything will run smoothly. For example I need the image and the caption.

This is what I have done so far, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
instagramDataDictionary["image_standard"] = image as UIImage!
```

('image' is the image loaded asynchronously)

```
var cellImageView = UIImageView(image: allDataArray[indexPath.section]["image_standard"] as UIImage!)
```

Then I try to add the Image to the table but when I run the app nothing displays (I add the subview after the above code). Do I need to save the image in some other way?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use NSNotification to post a notification when it finishes downloading your image and add an observer in your table view controller and reload your tableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's the problem you're having, but Swift dictionaries can only contain data with the same type - only numbers or only Strings, not a mix of both.

This may be the cause of problem you're having?

Comment: Yeah I think that may be the problem, thank you for point that out!